# Why can't I correctly use ibatis

Tags: java, spring, mybatis, ibatis, spring-mybatis

I already induct the dependency of Mybatis, in way of pom. The part of the pom be like:

```
<dependency>
            <groupId>org.mybatis.spring.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>mybatis-spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

But while I am importing the package like:

```
import org.apache.ibas.annotations.Mapper
```

IDEA says "can't resolve symbol "ibatis""
And while I run the program, the terminal says package org.apache.ibatis.annotations doesn't exist

How can I fix this? The dependency of mybatis-spring-boot-starter should involve package org.apache.ibatis.annotations. Why can't it work?

I know I can use the dependency of ibatis-core instead, but is there any diffenrence between the two? Because actually I'm confronted with some other Error if I induct the dependency off ibatis-core like:

```
<dependency>
<groupId>org.apache.ibatis</groupId>
<artifactId>ibatis-core</artifactId>
<version>3.0</version>
</dependency>
```

Thank u for ur Patience and making my day. I will be quite happy if u can provide me with ur selfless help :)

I have tried using maven clean and install, but it doesn't work

Comment: ibatis was retired by apache in 2010; you should use mybatis instead.  So avoid the org.apache.ibatis* dependencies.  Here's the pom for mybatis spring-boot starter kit, take note of their dependency list;  https://github.com/mybatis/spring-boot-starter/blob/master/pom.xml

Comment: So in what way can I use mapper in mybatis? These sentence should work fine because it come from a working project. However, it's not working in my computer. The information I get from Internet is that the denpendency of "mybatis-spring-boot-starter" should work fine with "import org.apache.ibatis.annotations.Mapper". Is there any possibility that the problem come from maven?

Comment: Wait are you trying to recompile some very old code that used ibatis, or build a new project using mybatis?